# Python variable referencing

Tags: python

So this is probably a stupid question, but it hard for me to word so it's really hard to google. How does python's referencing work? Most specifically, I've been working on learning backpropagation in neural networks, and as I was making a simple test network I had a problem. Here's the code to start:

```
out = self.nodes[-1]
for i in range(len(self.nodes)):
 for j in range(len(self.nodes[i])):
  self.nodes[i][j]=0.0
return out
```

If I run it like this it returns 0.0 everytime, but it will accurately turn out a number if I comment out the reset. How can I get out to reference the value not the variable?

Comment: What your code is supposed to do?

Comment: Why not just return self.nodes[-1] ?

Comment: I suspect you set up a list of lists without creating a new value for each nested list; a classic Python beginner mistake. How is `self.nodes` built?

Comment: Simone it's just a snipit. 
@doctorlove because nodes is a global and I want it reset to 0.0 before I stop the function

Comment: @Pieters here's the specific line   self.nodes = [[0.0 for i in range(layer)]for layer in network]

Comment: @Hovestar: Then your question is more unclear than ever; that is the correct way of building a nested list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `out` to hold the values of the last list/tuple in `nodes` without them getting reset to `0.0` you need to either create a copy of that object (`nodes[-1]`) or manually copy them into a new list/tuple object, if I understand you correctly, and that's your aim.
You are currently just creating a reference to nodes[-1] before you interate through the 2-dimensional array and reset all values to `0.0`, which means, `out` will still reference the referent in memory that you reset to `0.0` values.

```
out = nodes[-1].copy()  # This is the list/tuple with the (non-reset) values that you want to return
...  # iterate through the array here and reset
return out
```

This will now return the **copy** (i.e. a new reference to a *new, unique* referent in memory) of the last element of `nodes` with the state it was in when you created the copy (before the reset iteration).

Not sure if I understood you correctly but forgetting that lists and tuples **are** objects in Python and behave as such is an easy mistake to make.

That means:
    l0 = [0, 1]
    l1 = l0
    l2 = l0.copy()
    l0.append(2)

```
print(l0)  # prints [0, 1, 2]
print(l1)  # prints [0, 1, 2]
print(l2)  # prints [0, 1]
```

`l0` and `l1` are two references to the same object/referent in memory. Through the `copy()` operation `l2` becomes a reference to a unique and *non-identical* referent in memory.

**Addition:** Please note that list.copy() is, as kindly pointed out in the comments, available in Python 3 only and returns a shallow copy. Use `copy.copy()`/`copy.deepcopy()` to create a shallow/deep copy respectively; this module is available in *Python 2* and *Python 3*.
Alternatively, a *shallow* copy of a list can be produced through `list(list_to_copy)`.

Documentation here:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html
- http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/copy.html

Comment: Note that the `list.copy` method was added in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks @JanneKarila, added your info and expanded on it.

Comment: A simple way to copy a list is `list(nodes)`. Also I'd just drop that Python doesn't have a notion of "primitives"; every value is an object and that's it.

Comment: @Kos: I agree that the term *primitive* is a bit out of place in the context of Python, thanks. Defining a list through `list(list_to_copy)` is a handy alternative, however, note that it creates shallow copies only.

Comment: Personally I don't like the "shallow/deep copy" terminology particularly accurate. I prefer to talk in "copying objects" and "copying specified subgraphs of the object graph".

Answer (score 1):

You need to *copy* the last row, not just reference it:

```
out = self.nodes[-1][:]
```

Lists are mutable; basically an ordered container of references to other python objects that let you add, remove and change references. By changing all values in a list, you are *rebinding* those references inside the list.

`self.nodes[-1]` is just a reference to that list of references. You didn't copy those references; you merely copied a reference to the container.

You *could* just replace the matrix again:

```
height, width = len(self.nodes), len(self.nodes[0])
self.nodes = [[0.0 for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
```

Now you rebind `nodes`, and create new nested lists, so `self.nodes[-1]` before this code would refer to the *old* last row.